# Arrays in highcharts

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am using highcharts to draw some charts for my website. I downloaded a simple example and wanted to make some modifications. The plan is to load a data from postgreSql database into a declared array, and insert it into data (in series in highcharts). However I come up with problem straight away, I declared an array called arr1, and put it where the data is:

var arr1 = [-2, 8, 5, 11, 17, 22, 24, 24, 20, 14, 8, 2];

data: arr1

and it returns the blank page, however:
data: [-2, 8, 5, 11, 17, 22, 24, 24, 20, 14, 8, 2]

works fine...
I am not using php or JSON, is there a problem with an array?
Any help is greatly appriciated!!!

```
$(function () {
var chart;
var arr1 = [-2, 8, 5, 11, 17, 22, 24, 24, 20, 14, 8, 2];
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo'
            data: arr1
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 3):

Missing `,` on the following line:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
                 ^
```

Comment: Cant believe it... Thanks a lot! Time to sleep now :)